# Marshalling UnmanagedType.Currency in a vb.net interop event

Tags: vb.net, marshalling

I'm trying to declare an interop event that passes a currency value back to COM, but am struggling with how to declare the parameter in the event.

I have tried the below code, but I get:

> BC30002   Type `UnmanagedType.Currency` is not defined.

```
Public Event AdjustmentSaved(
    amendmentId As Integer, 
    newPriceNodeId As Integer, 
    newBuyPrice As UnmanagedType.Currency
)
```

I have also tried the below, but then I get:

> BC30638 Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers.

```
Public Event AdjustmentSaved(
    amendmentId As Integer, 
    newPriceNodeId As Integer, 
    newBuyPrice As MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)> newBuyPrice As Decimal`

Comment: Perfect - Thanks for your help Jimi.